# Unable to retrieve Date of birth of a contact in iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cncontactstore

I am trying to retrieve a contact details from iOS, Using Contact store I was unable to retrieve the date of birth of a contact with my code as below

```
 var toFetch = [CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactEmailAddressesKey, CNContactBirthdayKey]

let request = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: toFetch as [CNKeyDescriptor])
do {
  try self.contatcStore.enumerateContacts(with: request) {
  (contact, stop) in
  if contact.givenName.characters.count == 0 && contact.familyName.characters.count == 0{
  print("empty contact")
  }
  else{
  self.localContacts.append(contact)
  }
  }
  }
  catch {
  print("unable to fetch contacts")
  }
```

Output it prints as :
(lldb) po contact

```
<CNContact: 0x7fc57864a8f0: identifier=177C371E-701D-42F8-A03B-C61CA31627F6, givenName=Kate, familyName=Bell, organizationName=(not fetched), phoneNumbers=(not fetched), emailAddresses=(
    "<CNLabeledValue: 0x608000277e40: identifier=93D6F4AF-5C10-43FC-8405-A8BB02F2F9F7, label=_$!<Work>!$_, value=kate-bell@mac.com>",
    "<CNLabeledValue: 0x608000277e80: identifier=EDDE51A3-7D90-4E3C-8F9B-A60EC5F34498, label=_$!<Work>!$_, value=www.icloud.com>"
), postalAddresses=(not fetched)>
```

There is no birthday key though i requested in fetch, Can you guys correct me if I missed anything?

Comment: You shouldn't rely on the debug output.  You should check `isKeyAvailable`

Comment: @Paulw11  When we try to check key availability it returns false:                              
(lldb) po contact.isKeyAvailable("CNContactBirthdayKey")
false

(lldb) po contact.isKeyAvailable("CNContactNonGregorianBirthdayKey")
false

Comment: So, the obvious question is, does that contact have a birthday?

Comment: @Paulw11 yes birthday there,  we are trying to retrieve contacts in simulator default contacts, I opened contacts app and verified date of birth is there .